# Change playback speed in flutter video_player package

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I want to change the playback speed of the video with the flutter video_player package and save it to the gallery. I changed the playback speed with the property controller.setPlaybackSpeed ​​but I couldn't find how to get the change information of the modified video.

```
Slider(
  value: blur, min: 1, max: 5, onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      blur = value;
      _controller.setPlaybackSpeed(blur);
      
    });
  },) ,
```

I tried to find it with controller.dataSource and controller.value properties but I couldn't find it

Comment: Why do you need this value from controller? You already have that  in the blue variable. Can you explain the usage because this code looks enough to change speed of video.

Comment: I will save the speeded version of the video to the phone memory with the gallery_saver package, but I could not find the speeded video information.

Comment: You already have that in blur. You can use that one as information you need. I think that might be enough for your requirement. I don't think video_player provide this kind of information because if the user is passing those information they will have those value already.